# to send list of int on http params on flutter http package

Tags: flutter

I tried to send list of int in params on http get method, my laravel backend cant recieve list of int from params and give error code 500;

```
getFilterContent() {
Map<String, dynamic> data = {'key': '1'};
if (saleFilter!) {
  data.putIfAbsent('sale', () => '1');
}
if (isNewFilter!) {
  data.putIfAbsent('is_new', () => '1');
}

if (pharmaciesFilter
        .where((element) => element.isSelected == true)
        .toList()
        .length >
    0) {
  data.putIfAbsent(
      'pharmacies',
      () => List.generate(
            pharmaciesFilter
                .where((element) => element.isSelected == true)
                .toList()
                .length,
            (index) {
              var list = pharmaciesFilter
                  .where((element) => element.isSelected == true)
                  .toList();
              return list[index].id.toString();
            },
          ));
}
if (selFilterPrice
        .where((element) => element.selected == true)
        .toList()
        .length >
    0) {
  var list =
      selFilterPrice.where((element) => element.selected == true).toList();
  data.putIfAbsent(
      'prices',
      () => List.generate(
            selFilterPrice
                .where((element) => element.selected == true)
                .toList()
                .length,
            (index) {
              // data['prices'].add(list[index].id.toString());
              return list[index].id.toString();
            },
          ));
}
return data;
```

}

final uri =
Uri.http(url, '/api/v1/categories/$id/medicines', getFilterContent());
print(uri);
//It print' http:..../categories/11/medicines?key=1&sale=1&prices=1&prices=2&prices=3'

Comment: the backend expects like this :http://....categories/10/medicines?limit=1&page=1&prices[0]=1&prices[1]=3

Comment: Can you help me please

Comment: List of which object you need to pass?

Comment: {'key':'1','prices':[1,5,3,5]} this a Map of String , dynamic not a List.